# Need to iterate through id's in an HTML form and change values

Tags: jquery, html, clone

I have a form, which I've simplified for the sake of this forum:

```
<form id="data0">
    <input id="name0" />
    <input id="address0" />
</form>
```

Using jQuery I need to clone() this and then change the ids of the cloned form to be name1, address1, etc.

Is there a way to do this without changing them individually like:

```
$('#data0').children('#name0').attr('id', 'name1');
```

Like looping through all the inputs and changing '0' to '1.' Thanks.

Comment: Try something like $('form input').each(function(ind,elem){elem.attr('id',elem.attr('id').replace(/0/,1))});

Comment: How are you appending/cloning them?

Comment: The page layout starts like this: `<form></form><button you click to add a new form></button>` and I'd like it to insert the new form before the button.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kq5jq/ This is functioning they way I want, but I need to change more IDs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would make use of the `.clone()` api in jQuery to clone the form `#data0` first. Then iterate the input element inside the form, replace the id and clear the value, including the form id. After, place the new form to body. So, you should have a counter for incrementing the form id when clicks the add button.

The following example use `data0` form as base for cloning new form.

HTML

```
<input type="button" value="Add form" id="addBtn"/>

<form id="data0">
    <input id="name0" />
    <input id="address0" />
</form>
```

JavaScript

```
function ReplaceID(element, suffix) {
 var newId = $(element).attr('id').replace(/0/,suffix);
 $(element).attr('id', newId);
 $(element).val(newId); // for demo use, change to '' to reset value
}
var formNewId = 1;
$("#addBtn").on('click', function(){
    var newForm = $("#data0").clone();
    $('input', newForm).each(function(index,element){ // iterate input element inside the form
        ReplaceID(this, formNewId); // replace id

    }); 
    ReplaceID(newForm, formNewId); // replace the id of cloned form
    $("body").append(newForm);
    formNewId++;
});
```

Working example : http://jsfiddle.net/TfDUE/1/

Comment: I'm lazy, just simply the parameter name. It should be `function(index, element)` http://api.jquery.com/each/

Comment: Thank you for the help, Derek. After a bit of tweaking I got it to work perfectly in my project.

Answer (score 0):

use like this example:

```
<form id="old">
    <textarea>Some Value</textarea>
    <input type="text" value="Some Value" />
    <input type="checkbox" value="bob" checked />
    <br />
</form>

<input type="button" value="Clone" id="clone" />
```

This jQuery works, including the textareas:

```
$( 'input#clone' ).click(
    function()
    {
      $( 'form#old textarea' ).text( $( 'form#old textarea' ).val() )
      $("form#old").clone().attr( 'id', 'new_form' ).appendTo("body")

    }

  );
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution just take out the `console.log` and `alert` :

```
$(":input").each(function() { //get all inputs

newId = $(this).attr('id');

   $(this).attr('id', newId.replace('0', '1')); 
    console.log($(this).attr('id'));
    alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yKZPK/